# C# - Load Type from Custom Assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm writing a C# application that might reference class library that I'm also writing. The class library is intended to be a template for other class libraries I might want to use. My intention, is to dynamically load and use a type from the assembly generated by the class library. I want to load the type based on a configurable setting. At this time, my setting looks like this:

"MyOrg.MyApp.Services.Example, MyOrg.MyApp.Services"

What this string means is that I want to use the `Example` class in the `MyOrg.MyApp.Services` namespace, which comes from MyOrg.MyApp.Services.dll. I based this setting format on the `type` property that's used in the `section` element for a custom config section in an app.config file as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309408(v=vs.71).aspx).

My question is, how do *I* load this assembly and actually get an instance of the `Example` class from this string? At this time, I have:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("MyOrg.MyApp.Services.Example, MyOrg.MyApp.Services");
```

However, when I run that, I receive the following error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'MyOrg.MyApp.Services.Example\, MyOrg.MyApp.Services' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.*

I know the problem is because a type is named in my string. If I just use MyOrg.MyApp.Service", the assembly loads fine. However, I don't see a way to load the `Example` type.

Is there a utility method that I'm overlooking that will allow me to do this? If not, how do I load a specific type from a custom assembly? Thank you!

Comment: Add the Class Library as reference to the. And you can use the classes the exactly same way you already do with references like System.dll or [your Dispaly Technology].dll

Comment: you can't load a type, you can only load the whole assembly that contains the type you want to instantiate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this. One way is to load the assembly from a file path accessible by your application, get the desired type using its full name, then use the static activator class to get an instance of it.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("file path to your assembly");

Type typ = asm.GetType("MyOrg.MyApp.Services.Example, MyOrg.MyApp.Services");

object instance =  Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
```

Keep in mind you won't be able to access members on this instance in a type safe manner unless you make it adhere to an interface and cast it to that interface following instantiation, but that is a different topic.